# addeventlistener to every item in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, addeventlistener

```
I have a node list in a variable 

    connectedAnalysis = document.querySelectorAll('.connAnalysisUl li')

each li represents some text which I want to be removed when clicked on that li tag. 

I have code like this 

    connectedAnalysis.forEach((item) => {
       item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
           e.preventDefault()
           console.log(item)
          })
       })
```

Then I've noticed some strange behavior. If I have 3 elements in my node list and if I click on the first one I will get console log 3 times, if I click on the second li I will get console log twice. So before I continue I would like to understand why this is happening and how to prevent this. I read a lot about event propagation and etc and nothing could help me to understand the situation I'm facing here. What I want is that if I click on any item it is fired only once.

here is the full code

```
    //here I'm defining some variables

 let connectedAnalysis = document.getElementById('connectedAnalysis')
 let getAnalyisisNameDiv = document.getElementById('resultConnectedAnalysis')
 let relatedAnalysisParent = document.getElementById('relatedAnalysis')
 let parentUl = document.querySelector('.connAnalysisUl')

    //here I'm listening for users input and then I query mongoDB collection, I'm displaying all the result as li items

connectedAnalysis.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      if (connectedAnalysis.value.length > 2) {
      fetch('/analysis/'+e.target.value).then((data) => {
        data.json().then((result) => {
          getAnalyisisNameDiv.innerHTML = ''
          for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            let liItem = document.createElement('li')
            liItem.className +="list-group-item"
            let link = document.createElement('a')
            link.href=result[i]._id
            liItem.appendChild(link)
            let analysisName = document.createTextNode(result[i].analysisName)
            link.appendChild(analysisName)
            getAnalyisisNameDiv.appendChild(liItem)
          } // for end

//here I would like to take all li tags inside my ul tag and when the user clicks on li item I would like to add it to the DOM

let analysisNameList = document.querySelectorAll('#resultConnectedAnalysis li')

            analysisNameList.forEach((item) =>  {
              item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()

                // creating hidden input tag and grab analysis id
                let connectedAnalysisID = document.createElement('input')
                connectedAnalysisID.type = 'hidden'
                connectedAnalysisID.name = 'connectedTo[]'
                connectedAnalysisID.setAttribute('value', e.srcElement.attributes.href.textContent)

//here I'm creating a remove button
                let removeButton = document.createElement('small')
                removeButton.className += 'ml-1 float-right removeConnectedAnalysis'
                let removeText = document.createTextNode('x')
                removeButton.appendChild(removeText)

//here I'm creating li tag and adding everything to the DOM

                let connectedAnalysisLi = document.createElement('li')
                connectedAnalysisLi.className += 'list-inline-item __connectedAnalysis'
                let connectedAnalysisInnerText = document.createTextNode(e.target.innerText)
                connectedAnalysisLi.appendChild(connectedAnalysisInnerText)
                connectedAnalysisLi.appendChild(removeButton)
                connectedAnalysisLi.appendChild(connectedAnalysisID)
                connectedAnalysisLi.appendChild(connAnalysisName)
                parentUl.appendChild(connectedAnalysisLi)
                relatedAnalysisParent.appendChild(parentUl)

  //here I would like to remove item which is added by the user
                let removeConnectedAnalysis = document.querySelectorAll('.connAnalysisUl li')

        removeConnectedAnalysis.forEach((item) => {
          item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
              item.remove()
          })
        })

                  })// addeventlistener end
                })// analysisNameList end
            })// datajson end
          })// fetch end
        } else {
            getAnalyisisNameDiv.innerHTML = ''
          }
        })// connectedAnalysis event listener end
```

I believe that I got lost in loops and scopes and some other thing that I'm trying to learn. If you could help me to better understand my mistakes I will appreciate this very much. Thanks

Comment: I can't replicate this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5xv9tr1j/ please create a [mre].

Comment: sounds like you are binding the events incorrectly. The issue is not in the code above, it is in code you have not shown. Betting you are calling the above each time an li is added so you are binding each time. First time it is one li, second, you have 2, and third you have three. So first has 3 events, second has 2, and last one has one since it was found once.

Comment: For better performance it is better to add only one eventListener, in your case on your `.connAnalysisUl` and inside your function work with `e.target`.

Comment: thank you all for your time and advice. @epascarello you are fully right, this is exactly what I'm doing and now I tried to move it outside of foreach but then everything breaks. I will put here all my code related to this issue and I will be thankful if you have time to take a look and give me some beginners advice

Answer (score 1):

You are much better off using event delegation, where you set up a single event handler at an ancestor of all the elements that could trigger the event and allow the event to bubble up to that ancestor. Then, at the single event handler, you check to see what element triggered the event (if needed) and act.

Here's an example of what you say you are trying to do:

```js
// Get a reference to the ancestor
let parent = document.querySelector(".parent");

// Set up a click event on the ancestor
parent.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Remove the element that triggered the event in the first place
  parent.removeChild(event.target);
});
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>   
</ul>
```